How do I add a "copy code snippet" option in React Markdown files?
I currently wish to add a feature to copy code snippets in my documentation, which consists of several MD files that will render in the browser when the respective page is clicked.
I would appreciate assistance in implementing a code copy option for all MD files, as I am new to the React framework.
page1.md
welcome to my documentation.

    ```js
        <head> 
            <script type="text" src="https://cdn.js"></script>
        </head>
        ```


It would be best if you first converted markdown syntax to JSX, Here is how to achieve that
First, you use a library called Markdown To Jsx
Second use a library called React Copy To Clipboard
I hope it is useful and this is a video explains that deeply
